# How would the graph of this look like?

Tags: graphing-functions

I asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872276/what-is-the-derivative-of-xi) long time ago; however, I forgot to ask how would the graph of the derivative, and the original expression $x^i$ look like. $i$ is the imaginary unit for which $i^2=-1$

Comment: It is not a function whose values are real. Only the domain is in the reals.

Comment: @Crostul So could I just graph it in the complex plane?  But I don't know how to necessarily evaluate a real number $a$ to the power of $i$.

Comment: In the previous question it is defined $x^i=e^{i \log x} = \cos \log x + i \sin \log x$. Now, plotting the graph gives you the unit circle.

Comment: @Crostul Ohhhhhhhhh. Ok that actually made life easier. thanks